# Ignore delete the row and continue if there is constraint violation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple DELETE statement: DELETE FROM [TableA] WHERE Id != 123
This should delete 1000 rows.

However, TableB has a foreign key constraint which references to [TableA].Id
.  The above DELETE statement would have encountered an error:  The DELETE statement conflicted with the reference constraint in TableB.

Is there a way to ignore that row and keep going instead of erroring this out? In another word skip deleting that row in TableA? Instead of deleting 1000 rows, I'm now only removing 999 rows?

Comment: You'll have to explicitly exclude the rows: `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE TableB.ReferencingColumn = TableA.ID)`. There's no "just do it for the rows where it will work" setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for FK

```
DELETE 
FROM [TableA] a
WHERE Id != 123 
AND not exists (select 1 from [TableB] where TableB.FK = a.ID)
```

Comment: My TableB and TableA, in reality, each has upward of 20 million rows.  I worry about the performance this check may introduce.

Comment: @Fylix: that concern is (mostly) unwarranted, because SQL Server already has to effectively do this as part of checking the constraint. Besides, are you saying you have no means of testing it first?

Comment: @Fylix You could like try it.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll try these out.